# @ModelAttribute SpringMVC not working

Tags: java, forms, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a simple page where I can add/edit employees to a database when filling in a form (Note that mitarbeiter=employee in German - Sorry for that). The problem is that when I fill in the form isn't set in the Mitarbeiter object. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the model:

```
public class Mitarbeiter implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1280037900360314186L;

private int personalNummer;
private String nachname;
private String vorname;

/**
 * Default-Konstruktor
 */
public Mitarbeiter()
{
    super();
}

/**
 * Konstruktor
 * @param personalNummer
 * @param nachname
 * @param vorname
 */
public Mitarbeiter(int personalNummer, String nachname, String vorname) {
    super();
    this.personalNummer = personalNummer;
    this.nachname = nachname;
    this.vorname = vorname;
}
public int getPersonalNummer() {
    return personalNummer;
}
public String getNachname() {
    return nachname;
}
public String getVorname() {
    return vorname;
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/addMitarbeiter" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addEditMitarbeiter(@ModelAttribute("mitarbeiter") Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter) {

    logger.info("Generating addEditMitarbeiter view");

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("addEditMitarbeiter");
    model.addObject("mitarbeiter", new Mitarbeiter());
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/saveMitarbeiter/" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveMitarbeiter(@ModelAttribute("mitarbeiter") Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter) {

    logger.info("Saving Mitarbeiter...");

    try {
        if (mitarbeiterDAO.getMitarbeiterByPersonalnummer(mitarbeiter.getPersonalNummer()) != null);
        mitarbeiterDAO.updateMitarbeiter(mitarbeiter);
    }
    catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        logger.info("Neuen Mitarbeiter anlegen...");
        mitarbeiterDAO.saveMitarbeiter(mitarbeiter);
    }

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/searchEmployee");
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/editMitarbeiter/{personalNummer}" })
public ModelAndView editEmployee(@PathVariable("personalNummer") int personalNummer) {

    logger.info("Generating mitarbeiterEdit view");

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("addEditMitarbeiter");
    Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter = mitarbeiterDAO.getMitarbeiterByPersonalnummer(personalNummer);
    model.addObject("mitarbeiter", mitarbeiter);
    return model;
}
```

Here's a snippet of the form which is supposed to be filled in and saving the employee or changes onto the database:

```
        <form:form name="mitarbeiterForm" commandName="mitarbeiter" method='POST' action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveMitarbeiter" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="personalNummer">Personalnummer:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="personalNummer" /></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="vorname">Vorname:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="vorname" /></td>
            <td><form:label path="nachname">Nachname:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="nachname" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Also here's the pom.xml if necessary:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>at.business</groupId>
    <name>business_core</name>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.2</version> <configuration> <url>http://162.253.124.18</url> <server>UnixTomcatServer</server> 
                <path>/home/porttosu</path> </configuration> </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Hello Jennifer try modifying modelAttribute="mitarbeiter" instead of commandName="mitarbeiter" in your form tag

Comment: Go through this link you might get some good information http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation

Comment: @Pradeep thanks, unfortunately no luck , but I will have a look at the link

Comment: if you debug is it coming to @RequestMapping(value = { "/saveMitarbeiter/" }, method = RequestMethod.POST) request mapping .Can you please confirm.If I am not wrong this should be Get and your request mapping is not getting called i.e controller is not getting hit it seems

Comment: Yes it is going into the saveMitarbeiter Function. But then if I do database requests, it fails because the object I'm passing on is null. I thought it should be post because if I fill in the form then click the submit - button I want to post the data or am I mistaken?

Comment: what's your stack ?

Comment: Spring MVC & Java backend, jsp frontend

Comment: Hi Jennifer can you edit your question and add entire controller class without cropping .Also try adding @ResponseBody annotation above your request mapping also do binding result check for your form like   public ModelAndView saveMitarbeiter(
      @ModelAttribute("mitarbeiter")Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter,
      BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "error";
        } to ensure that your form has no errors

Comment: Did you find some solution to this problem? I think it is because of the Spring security (SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.java).

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
@ModelAttribute("mitarbeiter") Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter
```

from

```
public ModelAndView addEditMitarbeiter(@ModelAttribute("mitarbeiter") Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter) {
```

It should be only

```
public ModelAndView addEditMitarbeiter(Model model) {
```

and do

```
model.addAttribute("mitarbeiter", new Mitarbeiter());
```

(object of model and not modelandview)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tried the changes, but i'm still returning an empty object. Am I supposed to change anything in the other methods to? The addEditMitarbeiter function is only supposed to return the view which contains the form to be filled in by the user. On clicking the submit button the data should be saved onto the database

Answer (score 0):

Everything is looking good. You are using **commandName** in form, this is a old way read request parameter values, use **modelAttribute**  instead of command name.

```
<form:form name="mitarbeiterForm" modelAttribute="mitarbeiter" method='POST' action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveMitarbeiter" >

...
</form:form>
```